# PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type for procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am making a procedure but I am getting a error(PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type) while executing statement in the line(EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_QUERY)`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SUMMARY(V_NDAY IN NUMBER ) IS
V_QUERY NVARCHAR2 (5000);

BEGIN
  V_QUERY := 'DROP TABLE temp_summary';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_QUERY;
END SUMMARY;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: I think you need to use `varchar2` not `Nvarchar2`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the solution , it is working fine now.
I am using oracle as DB
but i want to know why nvarchar2 is not working?

Comment: `varchar2` is an oracle-specific type that was introduced to circumvent the limitations of the original `varchar` implementation without breaking compatibility. For `nvarchar`, no such kludge was necessary, therefore there is no `nvarchar2`.

Comment: " I am getting a error " is not very helpful. If you want us to explain you need to tell us which error message you got.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the data type from 'V_QUERY' to `VARCHAR2` and not `NVARCHAR2`.

Answer (score 1):

Use VARCHAR2 instead of NVARCHAR2. This will solve the problem.